# Vagrant up error. VirtualBox writes the box to precise32, but it fails to rename it and gives error

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I try `vagrant up` and I continue to receive this code error. What is wrong with my system??

```
    vagrant up
    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    [default] Importing base box 'precise32'...
    [default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
    [default] Setting the name of the VM...
    There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
    for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

    Command: ["modifyvm", "61d768ff-adc4-4f66-a704-7f04b4f01639", "--name", "tmp_default_1382129134"]
    Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not rename the directory 'C:\VirtualBox VMs\precise32' to 'C:\VirtualBox VMs\tmp_default_1382129134' to save the settings file (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface I Machine, callee IUnknown 
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "SaveSettings()" at line 2527 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Edit: I am using VirtualBox 4.3 and Vagrant 1.3.5, so after updating VirtualBox from 4.2 to 4.3, I continue to have this issue.

Comment: Try upgrade VirtualBox + Vagrant to 4.3 + 1.3.5, also avoid using spaces in path.

Comment: Could you publish your Vagrantfile??

Comment: I'm getting the same issue..